# How to react if the OP requests the file with the answer content?

Tags: discussion, answers

I had a particular issue and I did not know how to react. After answering a question satisfactorily and obtaining the OP's validity, the step by step wasn't enough for him and asks me to send him the file with the final result. I did not know what to answer. The OP continued to send comments insisting with the request, arguing he was unable to make a circle in the question's application, until he got mad, removed the correct answer validity and delete all the comments. What is the right answer in those cases? Is there some kind of answer already formulated?

Those are just three commentaries I could capture before he delete them all:

[image: answers]

Well, the discussion has continued, as he has the habit to put comments and then delete them, here is the last capture:

[image: comments]

Since now he check and removed the correct answer validation twice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### We are not Fiverr.

That is to say: do not send your file. You are not obliged to do so in any way. If a user does not want to learn, and rather just profit from your goodwill, then this is not the right community for them.

If they get rude about it, flag the rudeness and walk away. You do not have to deal with this, that's what we have moderators for.

Comment: That's what I think but the situation surpasses me, especially after having created a good job in the answer. I think he stopped when I told him that I deleted the file.

Comment: Don't ever let yourself be browbeat into doing work for free, especially for random strangers on the interwebs.

Comment: Also, if you feel like you're being pushed into something you don't want to, or just are unsure what to do, you're always welcome in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot). A lot of experienced users and mods hang out there, ready to lend you a hand.

Comment: I will keep it in mind, I did not know that the chat was also useful for those cases.

Comment: @Danielillo chat is useful for, well, *everything*. Lol

Answer (score 2):

To build on the answer Vincent provides, with which I totally agree.

I answered a question some time ago that started abstract and slowly got more precise with actual graphic material. Reading between the lines, OP wanted examples to solve his problem. I provided a part of it and then OP added a bounty on the question. I felt like the bounty mechanism could quickly become an incentive to "Will you do my work for me?"

As a teacher, I was also concerned with [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110285/how-can-i-make-this-logo-look-more-obviously-like-an-icing-bag-and-a-crown) that got a lot of answers, as it became obvious fairly quickly that we were providing almost ready-made answers to OP's assignment, possibly hindering OP's learning process or interfering with the teacher/assignment.

You've been a stellar contributor lately and you obviously put a lot of time in your answers. I think if you get an intuition that someone is looking to get their work done by you, two things you can do:

- I don't have that much time so some of my latest answers have been
  hand sketched. While hand sketching is not applicable for the technical
  questions, it does somewhat ensure that the OP is doing their share
  of the work when the question has a more symbolic or artistic
  orientation.
- You could answer but try not to provide the exact end result the OP
  is looking for. Maybe you change a color or tweak a superficial
  detail a bit so that the OP actually has their answer but needs to create their own thing with their specific requirements and not just grab a file from your answer.
- [This question from Mathematics meta can also provide some
  inspiration.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution)

ETA: If you do get to the point that the OP requests a file from you, don't feel obligated in any way to oblige them. A serious participant to this site will either not ask or learn quickly that this is not what we are here for.

Comment: Thanks Emilie, I think next time I will be a little more courteously hard. As i wrote on the question, he was insisting with comments, one after another one, and after a while deleting them. That's why I didn't answer. I just wanted to know in those cases if there's a way to stop someone like that or a polite ready answer we can copy/paste.

Comment: Mathematics as a site is great at not doing work for the OP but rather pointing them in the right direction